# Telegram sendMessage API and char encoding

Tags: telegram-bot

I'm using API https://api.telegram.org/bot${botToken}/sendMessage via Javascript to send messages to my channel, and it works fine, but when I use latin characters like: é they are not printed correctly in Telegram, how can I solve this?

this is my code:

```
const url = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${botToken}/sendMessage`;
const data = new FormData();
data.append("chat_id", '-100'+chatId);
data.append("text", text);

fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', 
    cache: 'no-cache', cached
    body: data 
});
```

Comment: Telegram bot api processes strings as `utf-8`. Send `utf-8` based strings.

Comment: can you post the solution using the fetch of my example?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with JS.

Comment: It may be a problem with your telegram client, I've tested the code you've provided without a major modification. I was able to send 'é' and it displays correct on Telegram.